# (26,15): error CS0501: 'ZombieController.GetReferences()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been creating AI for a zombie and out of nowhere, I get this error message. Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
 
public class ZombieController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NavMeshAgent agent = null;
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        GetReferences();
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        MoveToTarget();
    }
 
    private void MoveToTarget()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }
 
    private void GetReferences();
}
```

Comment: As the error message states, implement `GetReferences` or mark it abstract to later implement it in a derived class.

Answer (score 2):

This code is causing the issue:

```
private void GetReferences();
```

It's because you would normally define a function like this, such as how you did
it for:

```
private void MoveToTarget()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(target.position);
    }
```

You would need to do this for GetReferences();

```
private void GetReferences()
        {
            //Type your code here
        }
```

Then you can call it in Update as you did using the code below.

```
GetReferences();
```

Basically, you haven't defined GetReferences();
Hope this helped! Let me know if you have any more questions.  :)

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, can you please just type the code that is supposed to work here?

Comment: I think I did it but now it says "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

Comment: Could you share the exact code that you used again? Maybe edit the question with the new code? This way I can run it and see the issue... sorry about the late response.